# Android permission and Buildozer requirements for Spotipy

Tags: kivy, buildozer, spotipy

I'm trying to do an android python app with kivy and package it with buildozer. I need to use the Spotipy module but the app crashes when I launch it.

I think the android permissions is the problem : I only put `Internet`.
For the requirements I have: `python3,kivy,spotipy`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use adb for reading logs. You must turn on adb mode in developer options, than connect your phone via USB to computer and run command `adb logcat`. After that you can read logs and see your real error.